# GET call, Invalid JSON error when Updating to Angular 9

Tags: json, angular, angular-cli, angular-httpclient, angular9

I am working to update my app to Angular 9 CLI and all of my NPM packages to the latest versions. But when I try to make a GET call to load the data on page load the page breaks with a 400 error returned from the server. This endpoint call breaks:

```
@Effect()
  getAllData$ = this.action$.pipe(
    ofType<DataAction>(DATA_ACTION_TYPES.GET_ALL_DATA),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.dataservice.getAllData().pipe(
        map(data => {
          const payload = new DataPayload();
          payload.data = data;
          return new GottenAllDataAction(data);
        })
      );
    })
  );

public getAllData(): Observable<any[]> {
  // code hits the dataEndpoint
  return this.httpClient
    .get(this.dataEndpoint)
    .pipe(map(response => plainToClass(DataV2, response as Object[], { groups: ['get'] })));
}
```

In the network tab I get a 400 error with this response:

[image]

Here is the start of my 400 console error from the GET call:

[image]

Here is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "9.1.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "9.1.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "~9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "9.1.6",
    "@angular/material": "9.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "9.1.6",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "~9.1.2",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "~9.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "~9.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "~9.1.2",
    "@nrwl/nx": "6.3.1",
    "class-transformer": "0.1.9",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "~3.6.5",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "~8.1.0",
    "moment": "~2.25.3",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
    "ramda": "^0.27.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.5.5",
    "tachyons-sass": "^4.9.5",
    "tslib": "^1.11.2",
    "typedjson": "^1.5.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.5",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "9.1.5",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "9.1.5",
    "@angular/cli": "9.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.1.6",
    "@nrwl/schematics": "8.12.11",
    "@schematics/angular": "9.1.3",
    "@types/highcharts": "5.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "fibers": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "0.3.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^5.0.2",
    "karma": "~5.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "ng-mocks": "^9.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.2",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
```

Everything works fine in Angular 8. This error only occurs on my current branch where I am trying to update to the latest Angular 9. But I'm not sure how a front end issue could be causing the error I'm seeing. Could this be a problem with one of the NPM package updates?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the headers being sent to the backend. This is an error generated in the backend, so I assume you pass a wrong content-type that is different to `Content-Type: application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- Delete node-modules folder C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
- Open windows powershell as admin
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install -g npm@latest
- npm uninstall -g angular-cli
- npm install -g @angular/cli@latest